# Minified React error #321 - React Typescript library build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am writing my own React library with Typescript. I have a lot of problems with building and using it. I am using webpack with ts loader to build files into `lib` folder. When I am trying to use my components from build

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from '../lib'

export default () => {
    return <Text lg>Blabla</Text>
}
```

I get an error

> index.js:9 Uncaught Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

What is wrong?

tsconfig

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es5",
 "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
 "allowJs": true,
 "outDir": "./lib/",
 "noImplicitAny": true,
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
 "module": "esnext",
 "jsx": "react",
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 "esModuleInterop": true,
 "declaration": true,
 "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
},
"include": ["src"],
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

webpack

```
const path = require('path')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/index.ts'),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../lib'),
    library: 'my-library',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "types": "lib",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.11",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.5",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot --config config/webpack.dev.js",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.19",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.19",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR I got this issue before. The issue may caused by [Have multiple instances of React](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react).
I got the solution from here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16029#issuecomment-570912067

---

And, this is how I resolve the issue with my package.json and webpack configuration.

1. In package.json:

- Move **react** into `devDependencies`.
- Add **react** into `peerDependencies` too.

```js
{
  "name": "react-customize-token-input",
  
  // ... omit

  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.10.2 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {

    // ... omit

    "react": "^17.0.2",

    // ... omit
  }
}
```

2. In webpack:

- Add **react** into `externals`

```
  externals: {
    react: {
      root: 'React',
      commonjs2: 'react',
      commonjs: 'react',
      amd: 'react',
    },
  },
```

Example: https://github.com/seawind543/react-token-input/pull/7/files#diff-7ae45ad102eab3b6d7e7896acd08c427a9b25b346470d7bc6507b6481575d519